# Matar un proceso en C# que empiecen por el mismo nombre

Tags: c#

Supongamos que tengo los siguientes procesos con los nombres:

proceso_1
proceso_2
proceso_3

Pues yo quiero eliminarlos todos independientemente como terminen el nombre de la cadena. 
Tengo el siguiente código, pero no es lo que me interesa ya que debería pasarle el nombre exacto del proceso.

```
 var resultado = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Tu Nombre de proceso");
        foreach (var item in resultado)
        {
            item.Kill();
        }
```

Debería ser capaz de encontrar todos los procesos que empiezen por el nombre "proceso_" y eliminarlos. ¿Es posible esto?.

Nota: El nombre completo del proceso es arbitrario, sólo se como empiezan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe un método `GetProcesses()` que te devuelve todos los procesos que están actualmente corriendo, puedes recoger todos los procesos y después recorrerlos y eliminarlos si su nombre coincide con tu condición:

```
var resultado = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (var item in resultado)
{
    if(item.ProcessName.Contains("proceso_"))
        item.Kill();
}
```